# mount Bottle.py app based on hostname / domain?

Tags: python, routes, bottle

Since bottle.py does URL prefix based routing for its apps, I was wondering if bottle.py could support domain based apps.

There was [an ugly hack](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.bottle.general/730) I found on the maillist but it does not seem work with

- default hostname failback
- wildcard hostnames e.g. *.mysite.com
- one route for multiple hostnames (this would be good for local dev work e.g. mysite.com and mysite.com.localhost will both work)

And I do not want to mess with nginx or other web server based URL rewrites

Anyone having a more elegant solution for Bottle.py apps?

Comment: Thats not such an ugly hack its the right way for bottle to handle different domains, my opinion would be slap up a gateway doing all the routing for you.